# .NET Reading/Editing Mainframe VSAM files

Tags: vb.net, mainframe, cics

I have seen application that are written in Java that can interface to CICS regions on the Mainframe(haven't seen the source code).  I am looking for an alternative to the Java method in VB or C# that I can use to connect to a z/OS Mainframe 3270 to retrieve records in VSAM files.

Any documentation and/or sample code it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some methods are discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5211623/624463).

You mention 3270; another method to access existing mainframe 3270 applications is via screen scraping.  This is often considered less desirable than the mechanisms discussed in the linked thread above, but is sometimes the only option when no mainframe person is available to create/modify the CICS application(s).

Comment: I currently support an old vb6 application that uses a screen scraping tool that screen scrapes what comes out of a mainframe application, but I am trying to get around the screen scrapes and access the files directly.

Comment: Accessing the VSAM files directly would be a challenge.  You might want to check with those responsible for the CICS application and see if they are willing to help you out by creating a more friendly interface than just the 3270 one.