# Data sharing between java web application and Mainframes

Tags: java, database, data-binding, struts2, mainframe

Hi we are developing a SaaS application, technology stack of Java Struts2, Oracle 11G, Amazon Web Services. Issue i am facing is, one of our client would like to integrate the database of ours into mainframes sys of their's. I would like to know what are the possible methods to share the oracle database safely and in mainframes(i really do not have any idea about mainframes). Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: try looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191632/which-is-proven-solution-to-connect-mainframe-and-java-which-is-best-in-mq-ser/5211623#5211623

Comment: Not a real question. You need to ask the mainframe guys what tools they are using and importantly if they have any ideas about how they would like to access the data and what they need. They might just want to incorporate some data once a day and they want to use ftp to get it, or they might want data as soon as it changes... huge difference, better ask them.

Comment: Kindly post questions that are not subjective and emphasize on logical problem solving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create web services in your java application that expose the data the Mainframe wants from the Oracle database. It will then be up to the Mainframe development group to choose the language and framework that best fits their environment to call the web services. Since Mainframe systems are heavily customized you need to discuss requirements with the Mainframe group before you start coding. You can’t just assume that the Mainframe will be able to call your web services with a specific version of Java and a set of Java libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I work in infrastructure for a global investment bank that has a mainframe at the core of their trading and settlements applications. My advise is to spend time with the mainframe operators, database, and development teams to get a handle on how other applications integrate with the mainframe and then follow suit.

Although the mainframe can do modern things, run Oracle DB, Web services  etc. I wouldn't expect to be able to steer that ship if they are not already pointed in that direction. It takes a lot of muscle to move the teams that surround mainframes. That isn't necessarily a bad thing, because mainframe services are almost always extremely mature and reliable and the result is outage free business. Trying to change and modernize the services, while well intentioned, tends to create problems and the mainframe teams usually don't have an appetite for that.

In my company, integration with the mainframe is done mostly by arranging flat file transfers which the in-house developed app will pickup and ingest. In addition there is a lot of MQ  traffic to talk to the mainframe.  Natural database is used but is not exposed to anything other than the apps that are under the direct control of the dev team.

When you finally land on a method to integrate, make sure you arrange dev access to a non prod logical partition of the mainframe. Do that in any case but especially if you will be using services on the mainframe that are not battle tested and/or not rooted in the mainframe world.